# Is there a way to access Splunk using SQL instead of SPL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, splunk, splunk-query

I've been having a very hard time using SPL to query data in Splunk... I wish to replace all of that with some simple SQL, Is that possible ? If so how ?

I don't want to pay a lot just to get Splunk training... would rather use my SQL skills :)

Hope you all agree and can help me find a solution !

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use SQL to query data in Splunk.  Introductory training in Splunk's query language is free.  Go to https://www.splunk.com/en_us/training.html, click on "Free Courses", and select "Free Splunk Fundamentals 1".
Splunk has a manual to help SQL users transition to SQL.  See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.3.0/SearchReference/SQLtoSplunk.
For general help with searching in Splunk, see https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.3.0/Search/GetstartedwithSearch.

Comment: One could use the [Splunk hadoop connect](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/solutions/solution-areas/big-data/splunk-hadoop-connect.html) and query using hive, Polybase, et. al. if a SQL query language is desired.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually working on a connector between Apache Drill and Splunk that will enable you to execute SQL queries against a Splunk installation.  The code hasn't been committed to Drill yet but you can view the pull request here [1](https://github.com/apache/drill/pull/2089).  Here is a link to the documentation [2](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/372aede8b672b06101f6d895c777110f681934e1/contrib/storage-splunk/README.md).